# add difference between two date columns using a window in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, date-difference

I have a DF of youtube videos `videosExtraInfoDF`. The dataset has in many arrows for each `id_video` and in the column `trending_date` vary depending on the date got viral. I want a new column with the difference between the min and max of this dates.

`dias viral` is the new variable I want to create and `trending_date` date which video got viral

```py
w = Window().partitionBy("video_id", "trending_date")

WINDOWvideosExtraInfoDF = videosExtraInfoDF.withColumn("minima_fecha", F.min("trending_date").over(w))\
                                    .withColumn("maxima_fecha", F.max("trending_date").over(w))

WINDOWvideosDiasViralDF = WINDOWvideosExtraInfoDF.withColumn("dias_viral", F.datediff("maxima_fecha", "minima_fecha"))\
                                                    .drop("minima_fecha").drop("maxima_fecha")
```

Then I want to eliminate duplicates:
`videosDiasViralDF = WINDOWvideosDiasViralDF.drop_duplicates(subset=['video_id']).cache()`

The error:

```
AnalysisException: 'cannot resolve \'`dias_viral`\' given input columns: [category_id, CA, EEUU, GB];;
```

There are another variable: for each country, CA EEUU GB

Any Clue?